# How to export models trained in AutoML to saved model or frozen graph?

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I have trained a model on Google Auto-ML. I wish to use it along with other custom models I have built, hence I need the models trained in AutoML in frozen graph or saved model format. Any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in Google AutoML, you can do it in your local machine and export it to AWS sage-maker kind of platforms and deploy it.

Comment: Do you mean train a model on local machine and then export? I want to be able to export a model that was trained using AutoML

Comment: So far AutoML doesnt have that feature.